# Convert whitespaces into whitespace in JAVA

Tags: java

I currently programing a tool for converting names and firstnames into some phonetic name and i've got some errors or failures when i run JUNIT. I explain when the user will enter a whitespace I want to keep the string like this.

Here is one of my class :

```
    public class Phonfic {



        public static String phonfic1(final String tampon ){
            if(tampon==""){
                return ""
            }
            if (tampon == null){
                return"";
            }
            if(tampon.contains("FRANCAI") || tampon.contains("FRANCOI")){
                String temp=tampon.replaceAll("FRANCAI", "FRANSAI");
                String result= temp.replaceAll("FRANCOI", "FRANSOI");
                return result;
            }
            return tampon;

        }
    }
```

I want to get "" as result when tampon =="" but it returns me a null into JUnit.
I hope i was clear enough. Thanks in advance for your help or advices.

Comment: try `if("".equals(tampon)) {` for comparing empty string instead.

Comment: Or `tampon.isEmpty()` (after `null` check, of course)

Comment: yep, do the null check FIRST. for example if(tampon == null || tampon.isEmpty()){ return ""; }

Comment: `tampton.replace("[:blank:]","\s")`